# Powershell Substring Setting Specific Cell Length

Tags: powershell, csv, substring

Been working on trying to Trim/Delete a data in Specific Row (Results)in CSV file to a specific length.  Keep getting an "Overload for Substring".  Any ideas?

```
$Csv = Import-Csv $FileIn
$CsvNew = ForEach($Row in $Csv){
$Row.Results.Substring((0,[System.Math]::Min(254,$Row.Results.Length)))}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a simple mistake in your Substring usage. 
Remove one of the parenthesis.

From :

```
$Row.Results.Substring((0,[System.Math]::Min(254,$Row.Results.Length)))}
```

To :

```
$Row.Results.Substring(0,[System.Math]::Min(254,$Row.Results.Length))}
```

For the sake of readability, you could have put your substring count into a variable. The error would have appeared even more obvious.

```
$Csv = Import-Csv $FileIn
$CsvNew = ForEach($Row in $Csv)
{
    $MaxLength = [System.Math]::Min(254,$Row.Results.Length)
    $Row.Results.Substring(0,$MaxLength )
}
```

Edit:

Finally, please note that $CsvNew (that I took from your example) store nothing.
If you want to edit the CSV row content, use this instead.

```
$Csv = Import-Csv $FileIn
$Csv | ForEach-Object {
    $MaxLength = [System.Math]::Min(254,$_.Results.Length)
    $_.Results.Substring(0,$MaxLength )
}
```

This last snippet will actually edit $Csv variable content to trim your results column to a maximum of 254 characters. (It won't be exported to the file though. For that, you will need to export the new $Csv content using the ExportTo-CSV Cmdlet ).

Comment: Thank you!  That does resolve the code I have.  I think I'm still missing the mark.  The output is :
'
Results Field input= sometext
Output = 8
'
I was shooting for something that would limit the field size cutting off the extra data.  For example if I set it to 4, have the output = some.

Comment: Take a look at the last snippet I just added. You need to do it via pipe to edit the $Csv variable content. That last example will actually trim the value and the modification is done to the cell directly.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!